# Can anyone help me in this python problem : wolves and prey dynamics

Tags: python

Hey guys i am learning python this summer and i have a problem to do, everything is new for me if anyone can help: Given an ecological system of predators (wolves) and prey (deer), we are to study the dynamics of their interaction. we will study the evolution of their numbers in steps. At each increments of time of `dt=0.01` the following applies:

write the function

```
wolves_and_dear(deer_0, wolves_0, deer_growth, deer_predation, wolves_predation, wolves_decay, dt, n)
```

that will simulate the system n  times and find the maximum value of wolves in the system.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfwuT.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. We answer specific questions about problems in (existing) code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic template that should work, the formulae seem to be missing in the question, so you'll have to add them yourself. Learning to write code is a very useful skill, so don't copy and paste this answer, learn from it instead.

```
def wolves_and_dear(deer_0, wolves_0, deer_growth, deer_predation, wolves_predation, wolves_decay, dt, n):
    best_wolves = 0
    for simulation in range(n):
        deer,wolves = deer_0,wolves_0
        t = 0
        while t < 1:
            deer += deer_growth
            deer -= deer_predation
            wolves -= wolves_predation
            wolves -= wolves_decay
            t += dt
        best_wolves = max(best_wolves,wolves)
    return best_wolves
```

If you have any questions, leave a comment and I'll try to help.

Comment: Thanks for your help,  I just worked on the problem and got a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def wolves_and_dear(deer_0, wolves_0, deer_growth, deer_predation, wolves_predation, 
 wolves_decay, dt, n):

wolves_max =0

for i in range(1, n + 1):

     wolves = wolves_0 + dt * (wolves_predation * wolves_0 * deer_0 - wolves_decay *wolves_0)

    deer = deer_0 + dt *(deer_growth * deer_0 - deer_predation * wolves_0 * deer_0)

  if wolves > wolves_max:

    wolves_max = wolves

        wolves_0 = wolves

        deer_0 = deer
        
return wolves_max
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code and it worked perfectly. The trick is to know that your are dealing with a mathematical sequence:

```
def wolves_and_dear(deer_0, wolves_0, deer_growth, deer_predation, wolves_predation, wolves_decay, dt, n):

    wolves = []
    deers = []
    wolves.append(wolves_0)
    deers.append(deer_0)

    i = 1
    for i in range(n):
        deer = deers[i] + dt * (deer_growth*deers[i] -
                                deer_predation*wolves[i]*deers[i])
        wolve = wolves[i] + dt * (wolves_predation *
                                  wolves[i] * deers[i] - wolves_decay*wolves[i])
        wolves.append(wolve)
        deers.append(deer)
        dt = 0.01

    return max(wolves)

print(wolves_and_dear(1.5, 1.5, 2/3, 4/3, 1, 1, 0, 500))
```